# Typescript declaration file giving me error in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I'm trying to add a typescript declaration file in my node module but running in to an error when using it in another project in VS Code:

> Exported external package typings file .../ttk.d.ts is not a module

The ttk.d.ts file in question is [here](https://github.com/maexsoftware/ttk/blob/0d6e435d449a1549d22c0f3c5c96fb7c09f2a963/src/ttk.d.ts).

What's odd is that in VS Code I'm getting auto completion using the declaration file. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:** This is the test file importing the module:

```
const ttk = require('ttk');

const t = ttk.factory();
const r = t`Hello, ${'@name'}!`;
const s = r({ name: 'World' });

console.log(s);
```

Comment: How do you import it?

Comment: Updated post with that code. The typings is defined in package.json: https://github.com/maexsoftware/ttk/blob/ttk.d.ts/package.json#L26

Comment: Fixed dead link to tkk.d.ts in post; the historical link for package.json in your comment above is [here](https://github.com/maexsoftware/ttk/blob/0d6e435d449a1549d22c0f3c5c96fb7c09f2a963/package.json#L26)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the file is being declared as global code (because it doesn't have a top-level import or export), but TypeScript is expecting the file to be a module.

If you look at the `.d.ts` that's being referenced, the contents of `declare module "ttk"` need to be moved out to the top level so that the file is considered to be a module.

I sent a PR to fix the issue here: https://github.com/maexsoftware/ttk/pull/7

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, this was exactly it. Maybe I'm a bit dense but the documentation around writing declaration files is not as clear and concise as it could be. Thanks!

Comment: The docs actually seem to be wrong, if I'm looking at the correct bits. They show it wrapped in a module, as you had it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html#function-as-an-module

Comment: Heh, and it is about to be updated to have that fixed :) https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/declaration%20files/By%20Example.md